# Tkinter loss of focus after removing Title bar

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I need to create a tkinter window without the title bar so I've used overrideredirect(True) as per the example below and this works fine. The problem comes however in that I then lose the ability to set the focus (or have any sort of focus) on the buttons/App.

I need to be able to use tab and enter keys rather than the mouse (that still works) to select buttons. Played about with focus_force() but with not much success. Spent the night searching for a solution but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated - Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

Window = Tk()                  
Window.overrideredirect(True)
Window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)

b1 = Button(Window, text='PRESS ME 1')
b1.pack()
b1.focus_set()

b2 = Button(Window, text='PRESS ME 2')
b2.pack()


Window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want use tab and enter keys rather than the mouse, consider following code template.

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_tab(event):
    current_focus = Window.focus_get()
    if current_focus == b1:
        b2.focus_set()
    elif current_focus == b2:
        b1.focus_set()

def on_enter(event):
    current_focus = Window.focus_get()
    if current_focus == b1:
        b1.invoke()
    elif current_focus == b2:
        b2.invoke()

Window = tk.Tk()
Window.overrideredirect(True)
Window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)

b1 = tk.Button(Window, text='PRESS BUTTON 1')
b1.pack()
b1.focus_set()

b2 = tk.Button(Window, text='PRESS BUTTON 2')
b2.pack()

Window.bind('<Tab>', on_tab)
Window.bind('<Return>', on_enter)

Window.mainloop()
```

Remember when using the `overrideredirect()` function, it removes many standard functionalities.

Make changes as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks but for me that still didn't work, (when using overideredirect) I still can't get the window to take any sort of focus. Not sure if its a Linux (rasp pi) OS issue now? I may just have to remove the overideredirect but ideally didn't want the windows toolbar visible

Comment: Ideally it should work. I'm not an expert in rasp pi though. Is there any error or message which might help understand the issue more clearly.

Comment: Your code works but there's a problem with function `on_enter` since it invokes `b1` and `b2` but these buttons do nothing! I changed `b1.invoke()` to `print('invoke')` and the same for `b2`, now I can see it working.

Comment: Above code was just to showcase basic functionality. Glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

The overrideredirect setting tells the window manager to ignore this window. This has various effects only one of which is to prevent the window manager from adding decorations (the title bar and frame). The X Window System also defines [Extended Window Manager Hints](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/) and the [_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html#idm46635824617200) hints are available for Tk windows by using `wm_attributes('-type', hintname)`. What you want is a splash screen type window so calling `Window.wm_attributes('-type','splash')` will mark the window as a splashscreen window to the window manager and it can then apply suitable decoration.

Instead of using overrideredirect, try using the appropriate hint and all other functions of the window will work normally.

Note that the hint is read by the window manager when the window is mapped so if you are testing this you need to withdraw and then deiconify the window to see the effect of changes.